# Does the Gauss-Markov Theorem state that OLS is the only BLUE estimator?

Tags: blue, gauss-markov-theorem

I was reading through the proof on wiki. Which is the following.

\begin{align}
\operatorname{E} \left[ \tilde\beta \right] &= \operatorname{E}[Cy] \\
&= \operatorname{E} \left [\left ((X'X)^{-1}X' + D \right )(X\beta + \varepsilon) \right ]\\
&= \left ((X'X)^{-1}X' + D \right )X\beta + \left ((X'X)^{-1}X' + D \right ) \operatorname{E}[\varepsilon] \\
&= \left ((X'X)^{-1}X' + D \right )X\beta  && \operatorname{E}[\varepsilon] =0 \\
&= (X'X)^{-1}X'X\beta + DX\beta  \\
&= (I_K + DX)\beta. \\
\end{align}

Therefore, since $\beta$ is '''un'''observable, $\tilde\beta$ is unbiased if and only if  DX = 0 . Then:

\begin{align}
 \operatorname{Var}\left(\tilde\beta\right) &=  \operatorname{Var}(Cy) \\
&= C \text{ Var}(y)C' \\
&= \sigma^2 CC' \\
&= \sigma^2 \left ((X'X)^{-1}X' + D \right ) \left (X(X'X)^{-1} + D' \right ) \\
&= \sigma^2 \left ((X'X)^{-1}X'X(X'X)^{-1} + (X'X)^{-1}X'D' + DX(X'X)^{-1} + DD' \right) \\
&= \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1} + \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1} (DX)' + \sigma^2 DX  (X'X)^{-1} + \sigma^2DD' \\
&= \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}+ \sigma^2DD' && DX =0 \\
&=  \operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat\beta\right)  + \sigma^2DD'  && \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1} =   \operatorname{Var}\left(\widehat\beta\right)
\end{align}

Since ''DD''' is a positive semidefinite matrix, $\text{Var}\left( \tilde \beta \right)$exceeds $\text{Var}\left(\widehat\beta\right)$ by a positive semidefinite matrix.

---

The part that I'm trying to figure it is whether or not this shows that OLS is the **only** solution that is BLUE.

The first part showed that $DX=0$ and the second part said that the added variance on the solution is equal to $\sigma^2DD'$ which at very least is equal to 0.

The specific question I have that makes me wonder if OLS is unique is that I'm I'm not sure if $DD'$ can be a matrix where both $DX=0$ and $\sigma^2 DD'$ doesn't increase the variance.

Comment: In the future, please just edit your original post rather than creating a new one.  As far as this new version goes, the answer may hinge on what *exactly* you mean by "OLS," because when $XX^\prime$ is not definite, there are many solutions.  Which of these is your "OLS solution"??

Comment: @whuber by OLS I mean the argument that the best linear approximation for $\beta$ is given by $(X'X)^-1 X'Y$ given MLR 1-5 (I didn't realize a question could be reopened after being closed. Sorry.)

Comment: The problem is that when $X^\prime X$ is singular there is no "the best" solution.  Indeed, it's unclear what you even mean by a "linear approximation" to the parameters.  Don't you mean to approximate the *responses* with a linear function of the columns of $X$??

Comment: Assuming that $X'X$ is not singular, the answer is easy: there are other BLUEs, e.g. the method of moments estimator (see Davidson & MacKinnon, _Econometric Theory and Methods_, §1.5), but they must be equal to the OLS estimator.